# How to retrieve (or re-create) jenkins mailer plugin post build email text

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In the event of a Jenkins build failure, an email is sent out to all developers using the Jenkins Mailer Plugin. See https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mailer

This email is extremely helpful in quickly identifying those authors whom have recently contributed to the source code and may be the culprits for breaking the build.

My goal is simple:

```
String emailText = "Email Content Here";
```

i.e. I wish to retrieve the email text for my own needs and perform my own parsing on it.

My initial attempt at solving this problem was to fetch the console output using basic auth:

```
    // Credentials
    String username = "some.username";
    String password = "USER_API_TOKEN";

    // Jenkins url
    String url = "https://[my-company-domain]/job/Team-Servers/job/teamserver-asc/85/consoleText";

    String consoleText = getConsoleText(username, password, url);
```

This worked great! I was able to get the console Text. However it does not provide the authors as the email does... any idea on how to retrieve this email for programmatic purposes. Or re-create it?

The format of the email is:

```
Authors:
 John Doe

Changes:
    John Doe: ce1ec6623567802d2fbc2cb5fb194d927835e466 
    - src/com/a/somePath/someFile.java
    - ivy.xml


Build Log:
  [...truncated 147.59 KB...]
     [java] [GC 3779195K->1885262K(4954624K), 0.2512120 secs]
     ...

BUILD FAILED
/u/jenkins/workspace/somePath/build.xml:1761: Java returned: 1

Total time: 52 minutes 56 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Email was triggered for: Failure - Any
Sending email for trigger: Failure - Any
```

Answer (score 1):

How exactly are you achieving this ?? using Groovy scripting, Pipeline or using curl ??

Based on the info you have provided 
`"https://[my-company-domain]/job/Team-Servers/job/teamserver-asc/85/consoleText"`

You are directly pointing to the buildNumber(85) and reading the consoleText which works fine, so why not point to 
`"https://[my-company-domain]/job/Team-Servers/job/teamserver-asc/85/Changes"`
to get the Change implementor, if the data is not present then move to the parent folder like so
`"https://[my-company-domain]/job/Team-Servers/Changes"`
guessing(Team-Servers is the build name)
you will definitely see the latest Change implementors here.

Again need to know how your coding to provide better information

Comment: Thanks for the response brother!!! Let me check this out first thing in the morning!! I'll let u know

Comment: Also to answer your question I'm not sure how I'm going to solve this. I'd like to listen for build failures and the RSS feed seems like it'll be good for this?

Comment: I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Hey Rohit. I so "/Changes" does indeed point to the changes of that specific build, but it is not in plain text format. I can traverse the DOM and pull from there.

Comment: but this isn't ideal

Comment: Jenkins uses JavaMail internally so when a build fails or succeeds it just copies the data(text in Jenkins-logs,users...blah..blah) and  sends out a mail....What your are do now is readind data from the webPage directly....which is the wrong approach,as there are a lot of issues with this,like how do you know which  build is running ?? and what if the project changes ....all of which require you to go back to jenkins and actual see if things are still the way they are..

Comment: Again if your purpose is to re-create a mailer then just learn how JAVAMail works its staright-forward... if you wish to get the mail details(re-create) why not create another PipeLine project only for mailing purpose(logs,devlopers,culprits,devlopers who casued build failures....) and trigger it in your current Project

Comment: My purpose is not to re-create a mailer. My purpose is fetch the contents of the email on build failure.

Comment: There is an option for that too in jenkins, under the editable Email notification-->Triggers--> Failure Any(Add the culprits,devlopers recipient list) there is an Advance button click on that and you can send a another email to a list of people with the contents that you want on build failure only, just add your email there... hope that helps :)

Comment: Rohit thanks man but I need this programmatically. It already sends the email out on build failure.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `getCulprits()` function that you can call for a build (http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html)

Example

```
import hudson.tasks.Mailer;

def build = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("TestBuild").getBuildByNumber(4)
def culprits = build.getCulprits()

for(culprit in culprits) {
    println culprit 
    def id = culprit.getId()
    User u = User.get(id)
    def umail = u.getProperty(Mailer.UserProperty.class)
    println "Email address is " + umail.getAddress()
}
```

This will print output like

```
First_Last
Email address is first.last@gmail.com
Foo_Bar
Email address is foo.bar@gmail.com
```

If you combine this with the email text you already have, I think this does what you want.

Comment: Hey Kendall. You are right. This combined with what I have will work great. However I seek some further assistance regarding where exactly this code is executed...

Comment: Personally, I use this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Global+Post+Script+Plugin to execute a script after every job. I had assumed you were using a try{} catch{} block in a pipeline script, but maybe that's not true?